# IEEE references in alphabetical order or numerical order?

Tags: bibliographies, ieeetran, keywords

Thank you all for your time reading and replying to my question(s).

I am really confused about two major issues. 
Issue One: I am writing an IEEE conference paper and I am trying to understand why the reference list comes out in alphabetical order according to (`\bibliographystyle{IEEEtranS}`) [How to Use the IEEEtran LATEX Class](http://mirror.math.ku.edu/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/IEEEtran/IEEEtran_HOWTO.pdf). I have been all over the internet for 2 days now that IEEE ref. list should be numerically and not alphabetically ordered [Guide for Initial Review](http://www.ieee.ca/journal/authorIR.html). I have found that if I use (`\bibliographystyle{ieeetr}` instead of `\bibliographystyle{IEEEtranS}`) it moves all references in numerical order.

Issue Two: Why the keywords in the (`\documentclass[conference, 10pt]{IEEEtran}`) appear as Index-Terms and not Keywords? Based on my research I have found that is a matter of preference to use Keywords instead of Index-Terms. The solution to this problem could be simple applying (`\renewcommand\IEEEkeywordsname{Keywords}`). But again I am just curious.

If anyone could provide me with some guidance or a reference/bibliography to read upon I would be very appreciated.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The bibliography style depends solely in the conference's template, as this varies from each one.  It usually is `\bibliographystyle{IEEEtran}`, but could also take the form of `\bibliographystyle{IEEEbib}` or any other like the ones you mentioned (such as `IEEEtranS`).

You should really pay attention to your conference's specs, or if you are unsure then contact any of the organizers.

Regarding the keywords, I would keep my recommendation: stick to the template.

Comment: Thank you Mario for your recommendations. Maybe I should come in contact with the organizers for further details. I appreciate your time and effort.